# I have an error when I try to install Discord canvas easy

Tags: javascript, canvas, discord

During my free time I develop a discord bot, but when I try to install discord-canvas-easy. Error. Someone have a solution ?
I'm on MacBook Pro M1 Pro (intel chip)

```
luca@MBP-M1Pro-Luca IweZix-2.1 % npm i discord-canvas-easy@3.2.0 
npm WARN deprecated @discordjs/collection@0.7.0: no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated @discordjs/builders@0.16.0: no longer supported
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/luca/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/IweZix-2.1/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --update-binary
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/Users/luca/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node /Users/luca/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/Users/luca/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/IweZix-2.1/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/luca/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/IweZix-2.1/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.10
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.14.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.10.2/canvas-v2.10.2-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.10.2/canvas-v2.10.2-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.10.2 and node@16.14.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.10.2/canvas-v2.10.2-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.10 found at "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/luca/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/luca/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/IweZix-2.1/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/luca/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/luca/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/luca/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.14.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/luca/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/luca/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.14.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/luca/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personnel/IweZix-2.1/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/luca/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:325:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
{...}
```

I try to update node, update npm, install latest discord-canvas-easy

Comment: This library has 54 weekly downloads. It maybe that it just doesn't work

Comment: Do you have any solution to solve this problem?